# undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activesupport

I have a Ruby gem that uses this line all the time, for example to work with the `blank?` and `present?` methods:

```rb
require "active_support/core_ext/string"
```

Recently there was an update for Rails. I updated `active_support` to version 7.1.1. After this gem stopped working and immediately returns this error:

```rb
An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: require "active_support/core_ext/string"

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module
# ./lib/gemname.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

Almost everywhere there is a discussion about cocoapods, but I don’t understand how this can be related to my case.

The problem is solved by replacing it with this line:

```rb
require "active_support/all"
```

But why is that? This does not seem to be the best solution for cases where only a few specific methods are needed.

Comment: Your issue is here (caused by an addition in rails 7.1): https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb#L81. You will need to `include "active_support/deprecator.rb"` so that the method exists.